# Where does the verification code for gcloud auth login come from?

Tags: verification, gcloud, mapr

I am currently enrolled in ADM200, MapR Academy's free online learning program. I am using the "Set Up a Virtual Cluster" instructions, revised on 11/25/2015.    I am using a Windows 8.1 computer, and am attempting to set up a virtual cluster on the Google Cloud Platform.  On page 5, instructions shown here:

> 8. After the installation completes, restart the Cygwin terminal by typing exit at the prompt and re-launching Cygwin. Enter the following
>      command at the terminal prompt to authenticate:

```
gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser
```

> The command will generate a link, and then wait for you to enter a
>   verification code.  Follow the instructions to authenticate.

I tried my project ID:  `hopeful-buckeye-123456 (#1234567890123)`, using the whole thing, just part outside of the parenthesis, and only the part within.  Each time, I received the error message from the gcloud command:

> ERROR: There was a problem with web authentication. ERROR: (gcloud
>   auth login) invalid grant

Also, the instructions do not seem to address the need to select and pay for a Google server instance, and then continue with the lab.  My free trial is only 60 days.  I hope to hear from someone who has "been there, done that".

Answer (score 14):

Do you see a link? This is what I get when I run that command:

```
$ gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser
Go to the following link in your browser:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&prompt=select_account&response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute&access_type=offline


Enter verification code:
```

If I click on that link, I'm presented with a login screen, which gives me a verification code that I can then copy into the terminal.

In fact, even if that's not working, you should be able to use [my link](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&prompt=select_account&response_type=code&client_id=32555940559.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute&access_type=offline); they're identical.